# How to hide text content within an element but not hide child elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have the following HTML structure and I want to hide the dot inside the `td`. The constraint is, I cannot change the HTML.

```
<td>•&nbsp;<a href="">Link 1</a></td>
```

I've tried using JavaScript, but it doesn't seem to work

```
var str = $('.container table tbody tr td').html();
str.replace('•&nbsp;', '');
$('.container table tbody tr td').html(str);
```

Is there a pure CSS way to do it?

Comment: Link:-http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_align.asp

Comment: @Raziasultana and that link is relevant here because .....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With CSS you can "hide" that text with `font-size` for example:

```css
td {
  font-size: 0;
}
td a {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>•&nbsp;<a href="">Link 1</a>
    </td>
    <td>•&nbsp;<a href="">Link 1</a>
    </td>
    <td>•&nbsp;<a href="">Link 1</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Or with Jquery "remove" that text node using something like this:

```js
$('td').html(function(){
  return $(this).contents().slice(1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>•&nbsp;<a href="">Link 1</a>
    </td>
    <td>•&nbsp;<a href="">Link 1</a>
    </td>
    <td>•&nbsp;<a href="">Link 1</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @StacyJ The font size method here is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

When there's a will, there's a way. Not sure why your jQuery didn't work, but here's a CSS-only solution. Note that you'll need the styles on both the td and the link. Hit "Run code snippet" to see it work.

```css
table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

table tr:first-child td:first-child a {
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>•&nbsp;<a href="#">Link</a></td>
    <td>Text here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text here</td>
    <td>Text here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where does this div comes from ? absolute ? okay, but then width is null for the cell when content is removed from the flow. Can you explain upvotes ? do i miss something here ?

Comment: You also lose all alignment with this method.

Comment: Your markup is different from the OP's, he used `<td>` and you're using `<div>`.

Comment: Per above comments, I edited my answer to put the data in a table but kept everything else the same. It's a kludgey solution to a kludgey problem and it may require additional style depending on the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
// you may do something like this in pure css  


td {
    font-size: 0;
}
td a {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *content* and *attr*

**css**

```css
td:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  width: max-content;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**for hide text just add this class to element**

```css
td.hide-text:after {
  content: unset;
}
```

**or you can use `@media`**

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  &:after {
    content: unset;
  }
}
```

**html**

```html
<td data-text="your text"></td>
```